# "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: " when using execve to launch a Gtk program on ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I have the following c program which launches a Gtk Program on ubuntu:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    char *args[2] = { "testarg", 0 };
    char *envp[1] = { 0 };
    execve("/home/michael/MyGtkApp",args,envp);
}
```

I get "`Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:` " and my program is not launched.

I have tried setting `char *envp[1] = {"DISPLAY:0.0"};` and execute '`xhost +`' , I don't see the 'cannot open display' warning, but my program is still not launched.

Does anyone know how to fix my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *envp[1] = {"DISPLAY:0.0"};
```

Very wrong.  Separate name and value by `=`, and terminate the list by `NULL` like `args`.

```
char *envp[2] = {"DISPLAY=:0.0", 0};
```

or better yet, don't hard-code the display, and use Xauthority too.

```
char *display = 0, *xauthority = 0;
char *envp[3] = {0};
asprintf(&display, "DISPLAY=%s", getenv("DISPLAY"));
asprintf(&xauthority, "XAUTHORITY=%s", getenv("XAUTHORITY"));
envp[0] = display;
envp[1] = xauthority;
```

I'm left wondering why you give the program such a sparse environment, though – depending on how you're configured and what you're using, Gtk+ may not be entirely happy with `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS,GTK2_RC_FILES,GTK_IM_MODULE,HOME,LANG*,LC_*,PATH,XDG_*` etc. environment variables gone.  Why don't you just use `execv` or `execvp`, and just allow the parent's environment to be inherited?

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting the envp to this, and it tries to launch my application.

```
char *envp[2] = { (char*)"DISPLAY=:0.0", 0 };
```

But I end up with a Segmentation Fault (my program runs fine when I launch it via command prompt:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x007e5f4e in g_main_context_prepare () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x007e6351 in ?? () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x007e6b9f in g_main_loop_run () from /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x0041b419 in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#4  0x08049191 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffffed4)
    at main.c:471
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ended up with a segmentation fault in `MyGtkApp`, your app is buggy and this has nothing to do with the program you posted.

Some suggestions:

1. I would never use `0` instead of `NULL`, it is a pain generator on 64 bit platforms: use at least `(void *) 0`;
2. no need to specify the array size if you're initializing it;
3. the first argument is (by convention) always the program name, so:

   ```
   char *args[] = { "/home/michael/MyGtkApp", "testarg", (void *) 0 };
   ```

Comment: As long as prototypes are all correct and varargs aren't in use, I don't see why `0` instead of `NULL` would be a problem.  IMO the best reason to use `NULL` is because it is more idiomatic in C.